# Air Native Extension for OS X. The extension context does not have a method with the name

Tags: objective-c, macos, actionscript-3, air, air-native-extension

So, I built ANE, but seems, my ojective-c part doesnt work.
I try to call function from native code, and get error:

```
The extension context does not have a method with the name someFunction.
```

What should I do?

Here objective-c code:

```
FREContext AirContext = nil;

FREObject init(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[])
{
    return nil;
}

FREObject someFunction(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[])
{
    FREDispatchStatusEventAsync(AirContext ,(uint8_t*) "SOME_EVENT", (uint8_t*) "some information" );
    return nil;
}

void ANEContextInitializer(void* extData, const uint8_t* ctxType, FREContext ctx, uint32_t* numFunctionsToTest, const FRENamedFunction** functionsToSet)
{
    NSLog(@"Entering ContextInitinalizer()");
    *numFunctionsToTest = 5;

    FRENamedFunction* func = (FRENamedFunction*) malloc(sizeof(FRENamedFunction) * *numFunctionsToTest);

    func[0].name = (const uint8_t*) "init";
    func[0].functionData = NULL;
    func[0].function = &init;

    func[1].name = (const uint8_t*) "someFunction";
    func[1].functionData = NULL;
    func[1].function = &someFunction;

    // other blank functions

    *functionsToSet = func;

    AirContext = ctx;

    FREDispatchStatusEventAsync(AirContext ,(uint8_t*) "SOME_EVENT", (uint8_t*) "some information" );
}

void ContextFinalizer(FREContext ctx) {
    NSLog(@"Entering ContextFinalizer()");

    NSLog(@"Exiting ContextFinalizer()");
}

void ANEInitializer(void** extDataToSet, FREContextInitializer* ctxInitializerToSet, FREContextFinalizer* ctxFinalizerToSet )
{

    NSLog(@"Entering ExtInitializer()");

    *extDataToSet = NULL;
    *ctxInitializerToSet = &ContextInitializer;
    *ctxFinalizerToSet = &ContextFinalizer;

    NSLog(@"Exiting ExtInitializer()"); 
}

void ANEFinalizer(void* extData)
{
    return;
}
```

And here my as3 code:

```
public class MyANE extends EventDispatcher{
    private static var _instance:MyANE;

    private var extCtx:ExtensionContext;

    public function MyANE()
    {
        if (!_instance)
        {
            if (this.isSupported)
            {
                extCtx = ExtensionContext.createExtensionContext("my.awesome.ane", null);
                if (extCtx != null)
                {
                    trace('context is okay'); //this trace works
                    extCtx.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onStatus);
                    extСtx.call("SomeFunction");
                } else
                {
                    trace('context is null.');
                }
            }
        _instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            throw Error('singleton');
        }
    }

public static function getInstance():MyANE
    {
        return _instance != null ? _instance : new MyANE();
    }

public function get isSupported():Boolean
    {
        var value:Boolean = Capabilities.manufacturer.indexOf('Macintosh') > -1;
        trace(value ? 'supported' : 'not supported ');
        return value;
    }

private function onStatus(event:StatusEvent):void
    {
        trace('Event', event, 'code', event.code, 'level', event.level); //this traсе does not works
    }
```

Here is my .xml file, which I used to build ANE:

```
<extension xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.9">
    <id>my.awesome.ane</id>
    <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
    <platforms>
        <platform name="MacOS-x86">
            <applicationDeployment>
                <nativeLibrary>MyANE.framework</nativeLibrary>
                <initializer>ANEInitializer</initializer>
                <finalizer>ANEFinalizer</finalizer>
            </applicationDeployment>
        </platform>
    </platforms>
</extension>
```

And this script Im using for build ANE:

```
mv ../as3/bin/MyANE.swc .
unzip MyANE.swc
mv library.swf mac/
rm catalog.xml
rsync -a ../Obective-C/ANE/Build/Products/Debug/ANE.framework/ mac/ANE.framework/
adt -package -target ane MyANE.ane extension.xml -swc MyANE.swc -platform MacOS-x86 -C mac .
mv MyANE.ane ~/Work/_Projects/test/libs-ane/
```

ANE for OS X, using:

- AIR 16;
- Flex 4.6.0;
- XCode 6.1.1;
- Flash Builder 4.6;
- Mac OS X Yosemite(10.10.1).

Comment: Can you check to see if the context is null in the Objective C layer?

Comment: There are many reasons this may not be working and mainly to do with the initialisation process. You'll need to include more code to show us how you create the context both on the native and as3 sides and where you are attempting to dispatch the event.

Comment: @ozmachine I dont know, how to do this. I tried to create output file, but it seems that this code is not even performed.

Answer (score 0):

You define function in objc as

```
func[1].name = (const uint8_t*) "someFunction";
```

but call it from actionscript like

```
extСtx.call("SomeFunction");
```

Possibly a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the function on the AS3 Interface as this:

```
    public function someFunction():void{
        context.call("someFunction");
    }
```

Also on ObjetiveC side you are declaring 5 functions while you are only defining 2,change this:

```
 *numFunctionsToTest = 5;
```

to this

```
  *numFunctionsToTest = 2;
```

even when this is not causing the error